# Why is the compiler saying my function that updates a State Hook is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I'm new to learning React. I'm creating a tic tac toe game and I'm having a problem with my stake hook. When the game is over, I want to update the variable isGameOver by calling signalEndGame() within the function calculateWinner() (I'll point out where it is!!) . When I render the code, I get a message saying:

```
./src/components/Board.jsx
Line 112:7:  'signalEndGame' is not defined  no-undef
```

Any ideas on why I keep getting this error and how to fix it. (I'll only past code that is relevant)

```
export default function Board() {
 const [boardSquares, setBoardSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
 const [xIsNext, setXisNext] = useState(true);
 const [moveNumber, setMoveNumber] = useState(0);
 const [isGameOver, setisGameOver] = useState(false);

function signalEndGame() {
 setisGameOver(true);
  }

const handleClick = (index) => {
 const currentSquares = [...boardSquares];
  //check if square has already been clicked
  if (currentSquares[index] !== null) {
   return;
 } else if (calculateWinner(boardSquares)) {
   return;
 }

moveMade();
currentSquares[index] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
setBoardSquares(currentSquares);
setXisNext(!xIsNext);
};
```

Here is the return section

```
  return (
<div className="tic-col">
  <div className="status">{status}</div>

  <div className="tic-game">
    <div className="tic-row">
      {renderSquare(0)}
      {renderSquare(1)}
      {renderSquare(2)}
    </div>
    <div className="tic-row">
      {renderSquare(3)}
      {renderSquare(4)}
      {renderSquare(5)}
    </div>
    <div className="tic-row">
      {renderSquare(6)}
      {renderSquare(7)}
      {renderSquare(8)}
    </div>
  </div>

  <Button id="resetButton" className="btn-success" onClick={handleRestart}>
    RESET
  </Button>
</div>
);
}
```

rendering functions

```
      function Square(props) {
  return (
  <Button className="btn-dark" onClick={props.onClick}>
  <span className="cellXO">{props.value}</span>
 </Button>
);
}

 function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const winningCombinations = [
  [0, 1, 2],
[3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8],
 [0, 3, 6],
[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[0, 4, 8],
   [2, 4, 6],
 ];

for (let i = 0; i < winningCombinations.length; i++) {
  const [a, b, c] = winningCombinations[i];
```

HERE IS THE CALL TO signalEndGame()

```
  //Check to see if values in current square array matches any of the winning combinations
  if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[b] === squares[c]) {
    signalEndGame();
    return squares[a];
   }
 }
  return null;
 }
```

Comment: It seems that you are declaring the function inside the component and trying to use it outside. Or am I seeing things?

Comment: @PedroMutter sorry for the late reply. I have declared the function signalGameEnd() within the Board Component (At the Top)  and I am trying to use it within another function calculateWinner(squares) (At the Bottom). They are all part of the same jsx file

Comment: Ok, but it is declared and used in the same scope?

Comment: hers an exapmle of the layout

Comment: export default function Board() {...........}

Comment: function calculateWinner(squares).  {      signalEndGame() }